# OpenGeo GXP Examples

Tags: web-mapping, geoext, add-in, extensions, sdk

Looking at [GXP examples here](http://gxp.opengeo.org/master/examples/) they do not list the dependencies within the JavaScript file, so I was wondering how to make the files work. I would assume just copy the JavaScript file, e.g. viewer into my SDK app.js file and build that. However it just loads a white screen when I load it.

Any hints on how to sue these examples?

Comment: http://gxp.opengeo.org/master/script/ have the javascript files example http://gxp.opengeo.org/master/script/gxp.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For most components you add, the only dependency is the file that provides the component itself. On rare occasions, there may be a missing dependency. But in general, if you e.g. add `gxp.plugins.LayerManager`, you only need to add the `@require plugins/LayerManager.js` dependency.